# how to pass location to props when use "useLocation" react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, location, react-props, reselect

I use useLocation and work with reselect and Redux in React js.

```
import { createStructuredSelector} from 'reselect';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

I want to put the amount of location in createStructuredSelector.but ownProps is empty

```
let location = useLocation();
```

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
   getTimeToAttendTheExamPageWithID(ownProps.location.state.examPId)(state, ownProps),
});
```

How can I put the location value in createStructuredSelector?

Comment: The `useLocation` hook is only valid *within* functional components. You can wrap a component with the `withRouter` HOC and get the `location` object injected into props and then it'll be available in `mapStateToProps` for the `connect` HOC.

Comment: Is your component rendered via Route ? . If yes then you can access the location in `props.location` . If your component is not rendered via Route then i would suggest you to wrap the component with `withRouter` . Doing so you will get access to the location via `props.location` .

Comment: @Drew Reese                                                                                                   
   Yes, it works now, thank you

Comment: @Shyam   Yes, it works now, thank you